# WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8000/game' failed ( Symfony, Ratchet )

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, ratchet, symfony6

I am trying to make a real time chat using symfony 6, ratchet and javascript however I can't connect to the localhost even though the URL seems to right one when I look at it in the console.

Here is my commander

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

use Ratchet\App;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use App\Websocket\MessageHandler;

use App\Sockets\LiveChat;


class SocketCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('sockets:start-chat')
            ->setHelp("Starts the chat socket demo")
            ->setDescription('Starts the chat socket demo');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        // $server = IoServer::factory(
        //     new HttpServer(
        //         new WsServer(
        //             new LiveChat()
        //         )
        //     ),
        //     8000
        // );
        $output->writeln([
            'Chat socket',
            '============',
            'Starting chat, open your browser.',
        ]);
        //$app = new App('localhost', 8000, '127.0.0.1');
        $app = new \Ratchet\App('127.0.0.1', 8000, '0.0.0.0');
        $app->route('/game', new LiveChat);
        $app->run();
    }
}
```

Here is the code that inits the websocket

```
<?php

namespace App\Sockets;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use SplObjectStorage;

class LiveChat implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n", $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

w        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

and last but not least the javascript to connect to the websocket

```
var clientInformation = {
    username: new Date().getTime().toString()
        // You can add more information in a static object
};

var conn = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:8000/game');

console.log(conn);

conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.info("Connection established succesfully");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    Chat.appendMessage(data.username, data.message);

    console.log(data);
};

conn.onerror = function(e) {
    alert("Error: something went wrong with the socket.");
    console.error(e);
};

document.getElementById("form-submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var msg = document.getElementById("form-message").value;

    if (!msg) {
        alert("Please send something on the chat");
    }

    Chat.sendMessage(msg);

    document.getElementById("form-message").value = "";
}, false);

var Chat = {
    appendMessage: function(username, message) {
        var from;

        if (username == clientInformation.username) {
            from = "me";
        } else {
            from = clientInformation.username;
        }

        var ul = document.getElementById("chat-list");
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(from + " : " + message));
        ul.appendChild(li);
    },
    sendMessage: function(text) {
        clientInformation.message = text;
        conn.send(JSON.stringify(clientInformation));
        this.appendMessage(clientInformation.username, clientInformation.message);
    }
};
```

Any help would be really appreciated,
Thank you !

Comment: can you add the exact errors you get in the client and if any errors in the server (PHP) logs too. One question, have you set up SSL correctly on the PHP side?

Comment: The error is "WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8000/game' failed: 
(anonymous) @ livechat.js:6".
I don't have any other errors and everything seems fine on the PHP side.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use WS with localhost and WSS for secured WS using the assigned IP not localhost.

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/game'); // try changing WSS ->  WS
```

Comment: I tried that but it unfortunately didn't work.